# PDF Lib install fail on linux server. Using pecl install pdflib

Tags: linux, terminal, pecl, pdflib

I'm attempting to install pdflib on my server and receiving the error:

`configure: error: pdflib.h not found! Check the path passed to --with-pdflib=<PATH>. PATH should be the install prefix directory.
ERROR: /root/tmp/pear/pdflib/configure --with-pdflib=/usr/local' failed`

I am entering the following in terminal:

pecl install pdflib

`path to pdflib installation? :`

/usr/local

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it solved this way:
Downloaded latest http://www.pdflib.com/binaries/PDFlib/705/PDFlib-Lite-7.0.5p3.tar.gz

```
# cd /home/xxx/Downloads/
# wget http://www.pdflib.com/binaries/PDFlib/705/PDFlib-Lite-7.0.5p3.tar.gz
```

Un-tar-gzip it

```
# tar xzf PDFlib-Lite-7.0.5p3.tar.gz
# cd PDFlib-Lite-7.0.5p3
```

See, if and where it contains pdflib.h

```
# find . -name 'pdflib.h'
./PDFlib-Lite-7.0.5p3/libs/pdflib/pdflib.h
```

Install via pecl

```
# pecl install pdflib
```

If it asks for path, enter the same full path
/home/xxx/Downloads/pdf/PDFlib-Lite-7.0.5p3/libs/pdflib
See from installation messages, if and where it added file pdf.so (in php extensions directory, this dir name may vary but file pdf.so has to exist):

```
# ls -la /usr/lib/php5/20090626
```

change pdf.ini

```
# nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

adding at the end

```
extension=pdf.so
```

(You may want to add it in command line php conf /etc/php5/cli/php.ini too)

reload apache

```
# service apache2 reload
```

See, if this extension appears

- for Apache see output of phpinfo() function if there is something new regarding PDFlib
  PDFlib
  PDFlib Support enabled
  PDFlib GmbH Binary-Version 7.0.5p3
  PECL Version 3.0.0
  Revision $Revision: 1.80.2.2 $
- for command line

enter at prompt

```
# php -i |grep PDF
PDFlib
PDFlib Support => enabled
PDFlib GmbH Binary-Version => 7.0.5p3
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this up, was helpful to me today :)

Comment: Have tried downloading from https://www.pdflib.com/download/pdflib-family/pdflib-9/ (PHP) (tried both Linux x86 and Linux Intel 64), but the neither downloads have a `pdflib.h` file...

Comment: Unfortunately, as of now, these source files are gone and nowhere to be found. Best to try a different PDF library, since the company has gone closed source (sad).