# Installing pdf for php

Tags: php, pdf, ubuntu

After an OS update (Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS) my pdflib no longer works, so I'm trying to manually install it.
I eventually followed the instructions on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369279/pdf-lib-install-fail-on-linux-server-using-pecl-install-pdflib)

When I run

```
sudo pecl install pdflib
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ls_libpdf
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install pear

```
apt-get install php-pear
pecl install pdflib
```

The ask be: 'path to pdflib installation? : ' enter '/usr/local'

Comment: Thank you! It seems that it was the path that was the problem as php-pear was already installed.