# Error installing PDFlib

Tags: php, pdflib

after much searching and testing classes and libraries that would generate a PDF from a html, give up and left to use PDFlib, by speaking it is more worked, but at least I know I must support the community.

But I'm stuck at the beginning.

I give the following command to install

```
pecl install pdflib
```

and it is giving error at the end:

```
downloading pdflib-3.0.4.tgz ...
Starting to download pdflib-3.0.4.tgz (27,043 bytes)
.........done: 27,043 bytes
7 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20121113
Zend Module Api No:      20121212
Zend Extension Api No:   220121212
path to pdflib installation? : /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/all-plugins-necessary    
building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootqJIDAR/pdflib-3.0.4
running: /tmp/pear/temp/pdflib/configure --with-pdflib=/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/all-plugins-necessary
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php5/20121212
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php5
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for PDFlib support... yes, shared
checking for g++... no
checking for c++... no
checking for gpp... no
checking for aCC... no
checking for CC... no
checking for cxx... no
checking for cc++... no
checking for cl.exe... no
checking for FCC... no
checking for KCC... no
checking for RCC... no
checking for xlC_r... no
checking for xlC... no
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... no
checking whether g++ accepts -g... no
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... /lib/cpp
configure: error: in `/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootqJIDAR/pdflib-3.0.4':
configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/pdflib/configure --with-pdflib=/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/all-plugins-necessary' failed
```

Can anyone help me telling what lack I install or configure?

Comment: It looks like the problem is because you have spaces in the path name of PDFlib. Try moving it to a folder without spaces and configure and make again.

Comment: Okay, after your edit I've really got no idea. That new error you have posted says literally nothing. We need the log of what happened during the configure step.

Comment: guy open the console.log but did not understand anything of what was inside it.

Comment: Your new log indicates that your system doesn't have a C++ compiler. Assuming you are running something with apt, then do `sudo apt-get install g++`.

Comment: Cris looks like it worked but when I go on my php page and make a $ pdf = PDF_new (); of an error 500. But it was anyway. I put a question to give up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
As Chris said in the comments, it does indicate you do not have a c compiler installed.

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

---

If it still doesn't work after installing g++, then try the below steps.

You may need to install the specific PHP PDFlib version downloaded directly from their site, then install via pecl.

http://www.pdflib.com/download/pdflib-family/pdflib-9/

Someone else resolved the problem this way, see the following post for full setup instructions:

[PDF Lib install fail on linux server. Using pecl install pdflib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369279/pdf-lib-install-fail-on-linux-server-using-pecl-install-pdflib?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: I looked at the answer seems to be the same mistake as mine, but I did not understand what you have to do. Which route do I have for the momemnto he asks me?